# How do I search index of matrix in file?

Tags: c++, algorithm, file, matrix, tensor

Suppose, I have a file with 3 column. first 2 column is index of matrix and 3rd column is value of that position in a matrix.

```
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 2 2
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 2 3
2 0 0
2 1 0
2 2 4
```

Now i want to search in this file everytime by this loop

```
for(int a=0; a<8;a=a+2){
for(int b=0; b<8;b=b+2){
for(int c=a; c<2;c++){
for(int d=a; d<2;d++){
//check here c and d is exist in file. if exist then return the 3 column value of that index position and if not then return 0 
}
}
}
}
```

I can not search the value in the whole file every time because it hold the position before the file read in past.please help  me I stack on a huge problem in my academia.

Comment: Can you explain in other words what the index of matrix should be? Never heard this... Or explain what your desired output is

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Are you trying to read in the file? What do you mean by 'search matrix index'?

Comment: That seems to be way to many nested loops for a 9 by 3 matrix. Not to mention that a couple of your loops only goes up to 8 and so one line will be missed.

Comment: i want to pass c and d value by a throw a function each time and check this c and d value is in the file or not if it exist in file then return the value of third column

Comment: if I understand correctly the file contains a sparse representation of the matrix with each line being `x y value`. If you want to "find an index in the file" you should read all the file into something like a `std::unordered_map< std::pair<int,int>,int>` and then search for coordinates in that map. In any case you first need to read the file. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution with std::map for your problem:
First we write every value with the index as key and the value as the mapped value in the map and then we can search for any index:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream stream(
"\
0 0 1\n\
0 1 0\n\
0 2 2\n\
1 0 0\n\
1 1 0\n\
1 2 3\n\
2 0 0\n\
2 1 0\n\
2 2 4\n\
");

    std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int> map;
    int x, y, value;
    while(stream >> x >> y >> value)
    {
        map.insert({{x, y}, value});
    }

    int c = 0, d = 2;
    auto pos = map.find({c, d});
    if(pos != map.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Value of searched index: " << pos->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: works also without `make_pair`: https://godbolt.org/z/Mvacao1Ka

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Updated the answer accordingly, thanks!